# regular expressions regex

Tags: regex

I would like some help with this problem that i have been struggling with writing a regular expression that matches a string that begins with a digit and ends with a digit and has 3 or more alphabetic characters between the two digits (no other special characters between the two digits).

Tested it on:

```
4trtrtr8 (match)

5yy&&7 (no match, there are special characters there!)

4VVB3 (match)

5wEwHSJDKLJFAKLJFsdsafasfa2(match)

3rt5 (no match, there are only 2 characters between the digits)
```

This is what i have as my answer for this problem...

```
^[0-9].*([A-Z]|[a-z]).*[0-9]$
```

the only problem is that i need this to give a no match for the ones that say so above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex fails to cope with the task due to `.*([A-Z]|[a-z]).*` part that matches any 0+ chars, followed with 1 upper- or lowercase ASCII letter, and then having again any 0+ chars.

You need to use

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z]{3,}[0-9]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PeXUo/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]`  - a digit
- `[a-zA-Z]{3,}`  - 3 or more (due to the limiting quantifier `{3,}`) ASCII letters
- `[0-9]` - a digit at the...
- `$` - end of the string.

Comment: oh ok now i understand thanks alot this really helps